# Can I put HTML in chrome extension's icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, extension-methods

Can I put a HTML code in my chrome extension's icon? According to the Google API ([setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText)) this isn't possible.
Is there any way to put it there?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

While `.setBadgeText` is, as implied by name, text-only, you can *draw* anything and set that as your icon.

You'll need to draw on a `<canvas>`, extract image data and use `.setIcon({imageData: /*...*/})` to update the icon.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056704/google-chrome-extension-canvas-icon) for a brief example, and maybe [this article](http://smus.com/dynamic-icons-chrome-extensions/).

It's not quite "using HTML", but with some work you can output anything to your icon.

Answer (score 0):

Badge is plain text only as can be seen in [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/extensions/icon_with_badge_image_source.cc?sq=package:chromium&rcl=1468797381&l=260). There's no way around.