# Magnifier for extension icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i pull with `textBadge` 4 figures number into extension's icon. The problem is: the number is different on every page and is hard to read (not aliased).

Afaik it isn't possible to make the font size of `textBadge` higher.

What could be done to make the number in `textBadge` better readable? I  already did dark background with white font - not a big improvement.

Is it possible to apply a kind of magnifier, which would work on the extension bar too? - i tested some of them, but they work only on the webpage area, not on the extension bar.

I'm open to ideas:)

Comment: Instead of relying on a badge being overlaid on top of the icon, you could create the entire icon with the number yourself using a `canvas` element and update the browser icon dynamically using `chrome.browserAction.setIcon`.

Comment: @PetrSrníček thank you for idea! I indeed tested this approach, like it explained there https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059608/1992004. But it seems i can under no circumstances overcome the limit of 32px of the width. Is it correct?

Comment: I believe that 32x32 px is currently the maximum supported size. It is the largest size mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#manifest).